# Looking for a TV show set on a space ship run by teens/young adults

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

So I watched at least one episode of this, but I can only remember one story and even then not the whole thing. It was set on a spaceship, and from what I remember it was fairly dark (lighting wise, not mood wise).

I think that the story I remember, there is something happening, and they have to stop it. There is a guy with glasses who might be melting? I think that the main characters were a girl and two guys. Girl had blonde hair in a ponytail? She ends up the last person conscious and manages to stop whatever is happening, and reverse the melting.

I think that I watched this in 2004/5 on UK early morning tv. Not sure if it was meant for kids but I think so.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [Silversun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silversun)?

> Silversun is a science fiction children's television series made in Australia by the Australian Broadcasting Corporation (ABC).
>
> The show features the adventures of the adolescent members of the crew of the Star Runner, an interstellar spaceship carrying a cargo of 550 cryonically suspended colonists to their new home, Silversun.
>
> In the year 2052, the Star Runner and its crew are two years into their 90-year journey to a livable planet 45 light years from Earth. The crew's goal is to get the "New Settlers" safely to the Silversun and begin a colony there. Because of the 90-year-length of the journey, the crew are mostly teenagers who will take over command of the Star Runner as the adults get older.

It showed around the right time, 28 June–1 September 2004. It has a girl with a blonde ponytail.

[image: Still shot from Episode 3]

I have found no mention of them actually melting, but Episodes 3 and 32 involved the cryonic pods beginning to thaw people as a result of malfunctions or environmental issues, including one of the characters fainting in the elevator in Episode 32.

**Episode 32**

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't it, but thank you for the help!

Comment: Ha, Silversun was my first thought when I saw the question title in HNQ.

Answer (score 4):

Was it space cases?  A nickeloden tv show from the 90s?

[image]

Comment: Sadly it's not this either, but I've just started watching it and I might never stop. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

There was also an episode of the infamous series "The Starlost" that meets the basic description.

"Children of Methuselah" - Thinking they've found the backup bridge of the Ark, they discover a module occupied by children who believe they've been piloting the Ark since it left Earth

Comment: Did it involve people melting?